# View child component in dynamically invoking component

Tags: angular, viewchild, router-outlet

I have component that is invoking in router-outlet from other component. On view this component appears as pop up. In this component I have child component which is accessible by View child. The problem is - when I try to invoke child component method I receive '... of UNDEFINED ...'. In time of investigation I noticed,that ViewChild is set before View is created, so we just don't have child component created.

This is how pop up component opened :

```
<tyc-side-bar [active]="isSidebarOpen" (onClose)="closeSidebar()" id="sidebar-schedule-closing" customClass="sidebar--schedule-closing">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</tyc-side-bar>

openEditClosing() {
    this.isSidebarOpen = true;
    this.router.navigate(['./edit'],
    {
        relativeTo: this.route,
        skipLocationChange: true
    });
}
```

View child in popup component. V is empty when setter is emit. On pop up component html child component is declared as tag:

```
  @ViewChild(ClosingGeneralSettingsComponent) _generalSettingsComponent: ClosingGeneralSettingsComponent;

  public get generalSettingsComponent(): ClosingGeneralSettingsComponent {
    return this._generalSettingsComponent;
  }
  public set generalSettingsComponent(v: ClosingGeneralSettingsComponent) {
    this._generalSettingsComponent = v;
  }


<tyc-closing-general-settings [isScheduleMode]='false' [isEscrow]='isEscrow'></tyc-closing-general-settings>
```

PS: here is how it looks like when ViewChild is set http://webdav.chisw.us/webdav/TYC.Web_-_Google_Chrome_2018-04-20_12.47.13.png

Comment: Share some code to help us understand better

Comment: Move any code that is trying to access the `@ViewChild(...) child` to `ngAfterViewInit`.

Comment: @TomaszKula, I have tried this. It not worked, because ViewChild is set before view is inited

Comment: I have solved the problem, just by adding setTimeout to method invoked from the component.